# WPF Image Control: Trigger stops working once Source is modified in code

Tags: c#, wpf

I am experiencing some issues when changing the 'Source' property of a WPF Image control.

I have three image sources defined:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BitmapImage x:Key="eyeSelImage" UriSource="/Images/eye-Sel.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="eyeSelHlImage" UriSource="/Images/eye-SelHl.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="eyeDisabled" UriSource="/Images/eye-Disabled.png" />
</Window.Resources>
```

My Image definition looks like this:

```
<Image x:Name="testImage" Width="100" Height="100">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource eyeSelImage}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource eyeDisabled}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

It works as expected. If the image control is disabled, the image changes. Once it becomes enabled, it changes back. I tested this by making a button (btn_DisableEnable) which, when clicked, toggles the 'IsEnabled' property of the 'testImage'.

However as soon as I change the 'Source' of my 'testImage' image control in code, the 'IsEnabled' trigger seems to stop working. I made another button and in its 'Click' event handler I do the following:

```
BitmapImage tempImage = new BitmapImage();
tempImage.BeginInit();
tempImage.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/testApp1;component/Images/eye-SelHl.png");
tempImage.EndInit();
testImage.Source = tempImage;
```

After pressing this button, the image's source properly changes to the 'eyeSelHlImage' resource. However the image no longer changes to its disabled representation and back when the 'btn_DisableEnable' is clicked.

What could be the problem? All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since dependency properties can be set by different mechanisms (triggers, styles, themes, inheritance and so on), it has been defined a "setting" precedence list.

You can find it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms743230(v=vs.100).aspx).

As you can see **local value** - i.e. if you set the directly property with code or by XAML, or by using the [SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method - has an higher precedence rather than **styles** or **triggers**.

So setting the `Source` property by code has precedence on what value your trigger may set.

This is the reason why, after you call your code, your trigger does not work any more.

Comment: I've seen these kind of explanations before but since the link you posted seems to be broken in every post I've seen, I can't find out the details (if I click the link I see "This topic is no longer available"). However you added a comment I've not seen in any of the other posts I've looked at. And that is that setting in code is also "local value". Thanks.
Is my only choice now to implement an 'IsEnabledChanged' event and manipulate the image there?

Comment: Yes @EEALNT, you can. Anyway you can also consider using [binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) (I suggest this way).